# How can I disable the USB power supply from Mac when it goes to sleep mode (including when it's installing updates at night)?

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, usb, power

I have a USB mouse that has some rainbow-like LED colors (gaming mouse). I keep it connected to my Mac via USB.

At night I just leave the Mac as it is (in sleep mode). The monitor switches off which is fine for me. But what happens is that the USB power is on. This mouse doesn't have a concept of sleep mode. So the mouse remains on throwing the light all across the room. I sleep in the same room where my Mac is kept.

Is there any way I can get Mac to disable the USB power supply whenever it goes to sleep mode? I want to keep it disabled at night somehow so that I can sleep without disturbance. I've heard that Mac wakes up in the middle of the night usually to install updates. I don't want the USB mouse to switch on when Mac is installing updates in the middle of sleep.

I've been searching for a solution to this but I'm not finding anything. How can I disable the USB power supply from Mac when it goes to sleep mode?

Comment: Have you tried a bit of cloth over the mouse?

Comment: @benwiggy What a beautiful solution! Love it! Problem solved I guess. Thanks! :)

Comment: A very "Apple" solution. Coming from the PC world it is weird to think of this as an acceptable answer.